# How do I specify the base file path to import files in Cypress.io?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I want to import my locale file `locale/pages.js` into a test so that I don't hardcode locale strings, but the locale file imports other things like constants using statements like:

```
import { PRODUCT_NAME } from 'config/general';
```

The `config` and `locale` directories are inside `src` directory, but `cypress` directory is at the project root. So to refer to the locale file, I have to specify from `'cypress/integration/test.spec.js'` the relative path `'../../src/locale/pages.js'`. I would rather be able to use `locale/pages.js`, but at least this gets me access to the file. But at this point, the import of the config file fails.

How can I specify the base path for imports so that I don't have to worry about where the current file is relative to the file to be imported?

Comment: Hi @ashley-wilson I've exactly the same question and problem. Did you finally solve it ?

Comment: @jmcollin92 I haven't; still using the full relative path.

Answer (score 0):

You can use webpack preprocessor and configure it on cypress plugins. You will find more info here: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/3262

Comment: Thanks for your answer Gonzalo, but I think it would be helpful for visitors to this page to see a solution that works instead of a link to a discussion. Could you please edit your answer to recommend a minimalist solution that works in the general case?

Answer (score -2):

We may load js file by appending 'script' tag in DOM.
Try the below code:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');          
script.src = PATH;
script.onload =  function(){
    FILE LOADED           
};
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Ahishek, but my question is about ECMAScript import statements being used to chain-load files. 
Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

What you have specified is the generic way of inserting JavaScript files into the body of a HTML file, which is completely different to what the question is about.